# SQL ERROR == 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

I am started to learn SQL and I am receiving an error as Subquery returns more than 1 row. 
In this query I am trying to create a table which include customer on both orders and customers table.
Where am I doing wrong?

```
 SELECT (SELECT DISTINCT customerNumber FROM orders),
        (SELECT customerName FROM customers WHERE customerNumber = (SELECT DISTINCT customerNumber FROM orders));
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.  Also, explain what you don't understand.  The error seems quite clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.

There are different types of subqueries in SQL.  A critical distinction is based on the number of rows:

- A subquery that returns more than one row (and often more than one column) is a *derived table*.
- Some subqueries are special.  They return at most one row and typically one column.  These are *scalar subqueries*.

A scalar subquery can be used where a constant expression would be used.  For instance, you can use a constant for `=` or in a `select`.  However, you cannot use a set in those locations.

Your query is confusing these types of subqueries.  You haven't specified what you want to do, but the entire query needs to be re-written, presumably using `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

You simple do `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.customerNumber, c.customerName
FROM orders o INNER JOIN
     customers C
     ON C.customerNumber = o.customerNumber;
```

Customer table contains multiple customers associated with orders, So subquery will return more than one record.

So, here subquery won't work. Do `INNER JOIN` instead.